# Как на C# работать с телеграмм api?

Tags: c#, telegram

Пробовал библиотеку TLSharp, но ничего не вышло.
Нужно

1. Разослать сообщение человеку(людям в группе).
2. Узнать, как только мне написали, кто написал и текст сообщения.

Как такое реализовать в программе на C#? А то примеры из сети что-то не работают у меня.

Comment: Вопрос уже был оформлен. Поподробнее, в след. статье:
https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/103396/

Comment: это не бот. Мне нужен обычный клиент для пользователя, а не для бота

Comment: Чем вас не устроил TLSharp?

Comment: @123_123 тем, что если взять пример с сайте в строчке var user = result.users.lists   ошибка- он users не видит. И то, что я не знаю, как получить уведомление, что мне пришло сообщение?

Answer (score 2):

У Телеграмма своеобразное API ну и [TLSharp](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp) конечно сыроват. Но писать свою библеотеку уйдет куча времени.

Для начала я бы посоветовал вам разобраться в [API Telegram](https://core.telegram.org/api#getting-started) и [TL-scheme](https://core.telegram.org/schema). Без этого будет впринципе тяжело.

Перед использование API вам нужно [зарегистрироваться](https://my.telegram.org/apps) и получить **API_ID** и **API_HASH**

Любые изменения у телеграмма содержатся в объектах  `Update`
Для получения нового сообщения вас интерсует объект

```
updateNewMessage#13abdb3 message:Message pts:int = Update;
```

В TLSharpe, насколько я помню, они специально не обрабатывались. Но в классе `TLSharp.Core.Network.MtProtoSender` есть метод `HandleUpdate` В нем вы можете получить нужный вам `Update`

Для отправки сообщения есть пример в документации

```
//get available contacts
var result = await client.GetContactsAsync();

//find recipient in contacts
var user = result.users.lists
  .Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof (TLUser))
  .Cast<TLUser>()
  .FirstOrDefault(x => x.phone == "<recipient_phone>");

//send message
await client.SendMessageAsync(new TLInputPeerUser() {user_id = user.id}, "OUR_MESSAGE");
```

Если у вас нет контактов, вы можете их добавить

```
var userByPhoneId = await client.ImportContactByPhoneNumber("791812312323");
```

Актуальную TL схему можно смотреть [тут](https://github.com/zhukov/webogram/blob/master/app/js/lib/schema.tl). Это [git](https://github.com/zhukov/webogram) веб версии.

Comment: а что это за язык такой у них? и как с ним работать? ато я посмотрел и не въехал вообще- что куда тянуть с этого. Что с этой схемой можно сделать?если моя прога на c#- для не шарющих в этом

Comment: Помойму они сами его разработали. Если вы хотите писать для телеграмма, вам придеться самому в этом разобраться. Могу посоветовать почитать https://tlgrm.ru/docs#mtproto для понимания.